# Predicate to retrieve a user's followers

Tags: ios, core-data

Say I have the relationship

**Followers / Following**
`User <<--->> User`

As a result, UserA.following = [UserB] means UserB.followers = [UserA].

I'm watching changes through `NSFetchedResultsController` and need a predicate to simply pull the 1:Many relationship. If this was code, it'd be pretty easy, I would just say `user.followers`, but since the fetch controller needs a predicate, I'm stumbling up on how to express the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `aUser` is the `User` object, and your FRC is tracking their followers, then the predicate could be:

```
    NSPredicate(format:"ANY following == %@",aUser)
```